# How to match string in varchar field from one table with other table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

table1 having a single column:

```
id     |   sentence(varchar 255)
1      |   I am a boy; a good boy.
```

and table2 having two columns:

```
word    |   meaning
I       |     مين
am      |     هون
a       |     أيك 
boy     |     لرقة 
good    |     اشا
```

Now **I want to query both tables in such a way that I will get each word with its translation**.

For the sample data the query result must be:

```
sentence                  |    word_meaning (virtual column)
I am a boy; a good boy.   |  {"I":"مين", "am":"هون", "a":"أيك", "boy":"لرقة", "good":"اشا"}
```

As you can see in word_meaning column, each word has its meaning with json.

Answer (score 0):

What client language are you using?  *That* is where you need to split a sentence into "words" *and* where you will need to put the output back together after fetching the individual meanings.  Do not try to do it in SQL.

Comment: I want to do it in a single query. With only using mySQL

Comment: It might be possible with a long, ugly, slow, stored procedure.